# The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Tags: java, selenium

I have write a script for read input data from excel file,but gives me error into sendkeys where i use getNumericCellValue.
Please help.
This is my code

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\AMC test cases.xls")); 
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Clinic Basic info");
 WebElement creat_new_website = driver.findElement(By.className("createnew"));
 creat_new_website.click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("cname")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[12]/form/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/button")).click();
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[12]/form/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[7]/a")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("caddress")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(4).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("clocality")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(5).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("ccity")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(6).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("cstate")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(7).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("cpincode")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(8).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("ccountry")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(9).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
 driver.findElement(By.id("curl")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(10).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message mentions, `sendKeys()` receives `String` as parameter. To send `double` you need to convert it into `String`. The simplest ways are adding `toString`

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("cpincode")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(8).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue().toString());
```

Or using `String.valueOf`

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cpincode")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(8).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x.sendKeys(String.valueOf(someNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi simplest of all is to make the complete excel sheet column and row format to string